# Does IOTA have block finality (at the moment)?

Tags: transaction, confirmation, coordinator

As the title says i am interested in the block finality of IOTA.

In the long run there seems to be no instant block finality in IOTA because it is only considered confirmed as some number of tips are linking to it.

But as we have the coordinator at the moment does that make the blocks final as soon as it is processed by it?

In this context, what does the label confirmed mean in the block explorer?

Example transaction:
https://thetangle.org/transaction/YDJQANT9QSUKS9DLEUNETXVCKFWMYCJDSZZVZQW9OGNZJMNCZTDTJXSPVUCBR9MZGGFZEUCODOIWZ9999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes all transactions referenced by a milestone (emitted by the coordinator every minute or less) is considered "confirmed" and final

That is what the label in tangle explorer means.

In the future you will get a certain interval of acceptance (like in Blockchains - accepted after 6 confirmations for example in Bitcoin ). This level should be very very close to 100%, so that the chance to undo your transaction becomes practically 0. You will be able to choose which level you want to accept